# Convert change number to change id

Tags: gerrit

Is there a gerrit REST API to convert change number to change ID

Eg: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/23823/

Convert 23823 to I4f39e8d8cc22520cd36f83f8675a716cc1ade1d9

Thanks.

Comment: You should be aware that while each '_number' only maps to a single 'change_id', the same 'change_id' can be used in each project on the gerrit instance.  The 'id' field is mappable back to a '_number'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "change" endpoint to search for the change number. Ex:

```
curl -s --request GET --user user https://gerrit-server/a/changes/?q=change:32151

)]}'
[
  {
    "id": "code~master~I64f1c892c13a9bad903955678f104c34f36d1079",
    "project": "code",
    "branch": "master",
    "hashtags": [],
    "change_id": "I64f1c892c13a9bad903955678f104c34f36d1079",
    "subject": "This is an example",
    "status": "MERGED",
    "created": "2016-11-03 19:15:36.000000000",
    "updated": "2016-11-03 23:02:53.475000000",
    "submittable": false,
    "insertions": 80,
    "deletions": 29,
    "_number": 32151,
    "owner": {
      "_account_id": 3
    }
  }
]
```

And then get the "change_id" information. Ex:

```
curl -s --request GET --user user https://gerrit-server/a/changes/?q=change:32151 | sed 1d | jq --raw-output ".[] | .change_id"

I64f1c892c13a9bad903955678f104c34f36d1079
```

More info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the answer from Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira, you can use the ssh api (by default on port 29418) which provides a complex description of the change in multiple single-line JSON strings.

The first entry is the one you need, so you could process it with shell utils or as already described with a JSON parser:

```
ssh -o ForwardX11=no -p 29418 gerrit-server gerrit query --current-patch-set --format=JSON 23823 | head -1 | jq --raw-output ".id"

I64f1c892c13a9bad903955678f104c34f36d1079
```

If you need the reverse direction, you can feed in a long Change-Id to the same API and get multiple lines for all matched changes with the same Change-Id.

Answer (score 0):

I provide my method that how I use [pygerrit2](https://github.com/dpursehouse/pygerrit2) with Gerrit REST API to convert Change number to Change-Id.

Here is my python code.

```
import sys
from pygerrit2 import GerritRestAPI, HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
rest = GerritRestAPI(url='http://review.xxxxxx.com:8080', auth=auth)

change_num = "1234"
info = rest.get("/changes/?q=change:{}".format(change_num))
change_id = info[0]['change_id']
print(change_id)
```